# How to make a circular button out of a PNG image?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website with a lot of images. The concept is of a galaxy so you can imagine I have a number of round planets and I want to make them clickable buttons.

These planets are in PNG format with transparent background and I want the clickable area to only be the non-transparent area (which is the shape of a circle). However, I have not found a possible solution to do this.

I have also tried to put a transparent circle on top of the image, and put `<a href>` on the transparent circle instead of on the image, but this does not seem to work either.

What makes it worse is that I have overlapping images which might cause some of the solutions I found not working. For example I have two or three overlapping images and I want them all to be a button (linking to different pages) (and I have another image in its background) so I don't know what's going to happen if I click at the intersection of these buttons.

Some of the solutions I've tried are:

http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/Jyjjx/45/

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

http://jsfiddle.net/DsW9h/

http://bryanhadaway.com/how-to-create-circles-with-css/

A snippet of my code:

HTML

```
<div>
<a href="~/SomePage">
    <img draggable="false" class="AIcon" src="~/Content/Aicon.png" id="AI">
</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.AIcon{
position:absolute; left: 50%; top: 40%; width: 2.5%; height:5%; opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation: AAAIcon .5s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AAAIcon {
0%  {left: 50%; top: 40%; width: 2.5%; height:5%; opacity: 0; z-index:4;}
100%  {left: 78%; top: 20%; width: 32%; height:32%; opacity: 1; z-index:4;} 
}
```

As it is now the image is clickable within the whole square of the image, including the transparent area, but not all of the area is clickable (there are some patches in the image where it's just not clickable).

This is driving me nuts. Any pointers would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Are you open to learning SVG?

Comment: @MikeRobinson erm the thing is all the graphics have already been produced, finished a few months ago by another member of the team and it's not very nice to tell them to re-make everything over in SVG :( (unless it's actually very simple and I've misunderstood). but is that gonna solve the problem efficiently?

Comment: You said you've tried making a second circle that's invisible, why didn't that work?

Comment: @JeffArries only parts of the circle are clickable, for some reason there are unclickable areas within the circle. I suspect it's due to overlapping images but cmiiw.

Comment: I don't know if you've done this yet, but @freestock.tk 's answer should work for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three ways to do it:

**1**- In the following snippet, I have used a css circle inside an image div on the first moon.

**2**- Alternatively, got the same result on the second moon placing the circle on `div:after`.

**3**- A third method is simply the opposite of the second: create a transparent circle and let the moon image on `:after`.

The first and third methods allow you to use the moon as a link with `onclick` javascript mouse event. The red element is set with `pointer-events: none;` so it have no effect on the moons' hovers.

```css
body {
margin:0px;
background: black;
overflow: hidden;
}

#circle1 {  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: purple;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/YAWvTuu.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#image2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/YAWvTuu.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#image2:after {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#inactive {
  background: tomato;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left: 50px;
  height:50px;
  width: 400px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#third {
  position:absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#third::after {
content: url('http://i.imgur.com/YAWvTuu.png');
cursor: auto;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image1" alt=image><div id="circle1" onClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'"></div></div>
<div id="image2" alt=image></div><div id=third class="circle" alt=image onClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'"></div>
<div id=inactive></div>
```

Comment: yes I saw that. I tried but there are still unclickable areas within the circle, which I suspect is due to overlapping images. When I tried to move the image to a clean area with no overlap, it works, but when I put it back in the right place, the area map didn't exactly work as expected.

Comment: You can use `pointer-events: none;` to disable (for a while) these elements in front of the targets.

Comment: I tried putting that line in all of the other classes, but the link still seems to be dead in certain random areas in the circle. any idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: Ok last update: both methods on the snippet. Re-check please.

Comment: thank you so much!! yes yes this makes sense. Also I realised that when I applied "pointer-events: none", I didn't put it in some other text classes which I initially thought wouldn't have any effects... which later turned out that they do!

so I've tried making a circle on top of the image work. but your method is nicer design-wise! I'll try it and if I run into problems I hope you wouldn't mind giving me further pointers?

Comment: is a pleasure to help.

Comment: [**check this pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reVJjB) its the same as before, but now with some selectors by class (not id) and the css circle with percentage, so you can have several different planets with a reduced amount of code.

Comment: I forgot to ask: where do I add the `<a href>` ?

Comment: On the first method (circle embraced by the image div) its very easy `<div id="image1" alt=image><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><div id="circle"></div></a></div>` [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXdpOR). But I don't know if it is possible to set a link to an `:after` element (second method).

Comment: and would it be possible to position the background image? because my image has a drop shadow which makes the size of the image slightly larger than the actual circle. with your code the planet appears smaller than the circle.

EDIT: never mind, just realised I could alter the sizes in `:after` !

Comment: You have three options: **1**- prepare the planet images on photoshop (let them all following the same standards) or **2**- change the background size/position link:[**size**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) link:[**position**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) or **3**- change the css circle size/position.

Comment: enclosing `<a href>` around the `circle` div makes the whole square clickable :( putting `<a href>` inside the `circle` div doesn't correctly work either. it's such a shame!

Comment: ok forget the `<a href=></a>` and do the following: `<div id="image1" alt=image><div id="circle" onClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'"></div></div>` (It cant be tested on jsfiddle/codepen because it brings you to another place, but I have tested it here and its working).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've interpreted your question properly, but look into z-index. If there's elements overlapping each other, this will be a reason why they're not able to be clicked.

Comment: when I tried making a transparent circle to put on top of the image, I had placed it on the very top with z-index but there are still unclickable areas within the circle. :(

Answer (score 0):

So, you can wrap the planet or circle in an `<a>` tag, border-radius that `<a>` element to be 100% which makes it a full circle and then hide the overflow.

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/xcqy7r14/2/

Markup:

```
<a href="#">
  <canvas></canvas>
</a>
<br><br>
<a href="#">
  <canvas></canvas>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```